# Find a "ridge line" from a set of irregularly spaced points

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization, fitting

I'm solvind a slope stability problem whith the finite element method. As an output I get the square root of the second deviatoric invariant of the plastic deformation, which indicates the failure surface for the problem.

The problem output generates a data in the format `data={{x1,y1,scalar1},...{xn,yn,scalarn}}`. The following code reads this data from dropbox and contourplot it:

```
data = Import[
   "https://www.dropbox.com/s/vl4sx9adrm4e0d9/plasticsqrtj2462.txt?dl=\
1", "Table"];
gph = Graphics[{White, 
    Polygon[{{30, 10}, {50, 10}, {50, 20}, {20, 20}}]}];
plot = ListContourPlot[data, Contours -> 10, ContourStyle -> None, 
   PlotRange -> {0, Max[Transpose[data][[3]]]}];
Show[plot, gph, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> False]
```

Here is the output:

[image]

I need to find a function that fit's the detached region, in order to describe the failure surface as a function.

I need a function that return a [x,y] coords of a line. Like the red curve in the image bellow:

[image]

Any ideas on how approach this problem?

Comment: Use `Select` to pick out the data points in the set that have the values of interest (I assume maybe "larger than some threshold" could work), then feed them to `NonlinearModelFit` if you have a model to fit to, or use `Interpolation`, or `InterpolatingPolynomial`

Comment: This might sound strange but after labeling the axes, why would you need a complicated function when you have a picture?  For example, do you need to make predictions outside of *Mathematica*?

Comment: @JimB Yes, I have 1000 results like this in a Monte Carlo probabilistic simulation. I want to plot each failure surface as an isoline in only one graph.

Comment: In short it seems you want to find the "ridge line" from a set of irregularly spaced points.  If so, putting that description in your question might result in more responses.  I wonder if you used `Interpolation` to obtain a regular grid of points and then apply `RidgeFilter`?

Comment: @JimB `Interpolation` doesnt work. To much noise in the solution (See Edit). But thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I solved like this:

```
largestdata = Sort[Transpose[ data][[3]], Greater];
newdata = {};
coords = {};
For[i = 1, i <= Length[data], i++,
  If[data[[i, 3]] > largestdata[[250]],
    AppendTo[newdata, {data[[i, 1]], data[[i, 2]], data[[i, 3]]}];
    AppendTo[coords, {data[[i, 1]], data[[i, 2]]}];
    ];
  ];

Clear[x]
model = a Exp[-k x ] + b ;
fit = FindFit[coords, model, {a, k, b}, x]
modelf = Function[{x}, Evaluate[model /. fit]]
pl = Plot[modelf[x], {x, 13, 30}, Epilog -> Map[Point, coords]]
pl = Plot[modelf[x], {x, 13, 30}]
Show[plot, gph, pl, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> False]
```

[image]

[image]

`Interpolation` is doesnt work in this case:

```
fff = Interpolation[coords]
Show[lp, Plot[fff[x], {x, 14.8, 29.9}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {0, 20}}]
```

[image]